# Google Drive change file modified date

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to see if I can update created and modified date of a mp4 file on Google drive.

This is not a question from a developer stand point but anything that can help me to get the job done would work. That said, if there is some way in Google Drive UI (Web App or smart phone app etc.) or using [Google's API harness][1]
to update the modified date of a file, I am ok with it. If your answer includes using API harness, please let me know where can I get the values for the API's parameters so I can run the API call from my login.

Just curious, if I somehow manage to update the modified time of the same file on my computer's hard drive, and then upload it (replace/revise an existing file on Google drive) would it read the meta-data from the file, or Google would use the time I uploaded the document as "modified date"?

Please note:
This is not specifically Google Drive API question, but if Google has an API test harness and I can put in some parameters there to update the file meta-data, I do not mind going to that route.